# Можно ли требовать от хостинг-провайдера блокировки клиента, который пытается взломать мой сайт?

Tags: безопасность, взлом, юридические-аспекты

Есть данные с WAF о многочисленных неуспешных попытках взлома нескольких рабочих сайтов (эксплуатация уязвимостей, sql инъекции и пр.).

Часть IP адресов атакующих зарегистрированы в моей стране. При проверке через whois видно, что это хостинги.

Существует ли практика (юридические основания и пр.) и есть ли вообще смысл потребовать от хостера принять меры и заблокировать текущих арендаторов этих IP?

Comment: Имеет. Погуглите "абуза хостеру".